# Simple loop won't complete, cannot figure out why

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

**SOLVED!**

Turns out the if statement was getting stuck due to the text encoding. I sanitised the lines before receiving and it fixed the issue.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm currently writing a function that reads the last 5000 lines from a log file, loops through the lines backwards and then looks for certain text in each line.

It was working fine before and now it doesn't get through the entire loop if the text is not found.

Here is the code:

```
for line in reversed(log_lines):
    if machine_id_line in line and rating_key_line in line:
        # Currently only checking for ipv4 addresses
        logger.debug(u"Found possible IP addres in line %s" % line)
        ipv4 = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
        if ipv4:
            # The logged IP will always be the first match and we don't want localhost entries
            if ipv4[0] != '127.0.0.1':
                logger.debug(u"Matched IP address (%s) for stream ratingKey %s and machineIdentifier %s."
                               % (ipv4[0], rating_key, machine_id))
                 return ipv4[0]

logger.debug(u"Unable to find IP address on first pass. Attempting fallback check in 5 seconds...")
```

What it is supposed to do is look for a line with two strings (machine_id_line and rating_key_line), if it cannot find a line with both of these strings then it fails back to another loop which is below this one.

If it does find both strings the loop works fine. If I put a try, except catch around the first if statement it also works fine (but doesn't give any exceptions).

If it cannot find a line with both strings in it just dies and doesn't ever get to the last line in the code above.

I just cannot figure out why I should need to put exception catching over the  entire if statement.

Shouldn't the if be sufficient to check for the string?

Comment: What do you mean by `it just dies`? When you put a `try`/`except` block, does the code goes into the `except` block? And if so, what is the caught exception?

Comment: I just tried using `print` instead of my built-in logger function and now I see exceptions printed when running the loop. Let me check if I can figure this out. Might be a encoding issue.

Comment: Indeed! Turns out it was a text encoding issue in the log lines causing my if statement to break. I sanitised the lines in my log reader script and now it works!